# Spliiting and processing values one by one in mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to split values and process them one by one

value is below

```
[
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
    "FName": "06-2020"
  }
]
```

how can i split them and process it in mule4?

Comment: What kind of processing are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add this values to json structure like below

%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"name":payload.Fname,
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
"parents":[vars.SetParentId]
}

So that i can create two folders one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-map) operation in DataWeave to transform each element of the array.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map { 
    "name": $.FName, 
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder", 
    "parents":[vars.SetParentId] 
}
```